# Getting content of currently active Text component wrapped inside popover of antd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using **antd** components for my react app. I have a `Text` component wrapped inside of `Popover` component. Now in my case this Popover is applied to one particular column of table, i.e. every row-element in that column has a Popover component rendered for it upon mouse hovering.

```js
    title: "Name",
    dataIndex: "name",
    key: "name-key",
    sortType: "string",
    sortDirections: ["descend", "ascend"],
    sorter: (a, b) => a.name.length - b.name.length,
    render: (text, record) => (

    <Popover>
    <Text onMouseOver={handleOnMouseOverCommitId}> {name} </Text>
    </Popover>

)
```

I want to get hold of the row-element's value, the one contained by the above `Text` component whenever I hover over it. In this case the value denoted by `{name}` above.

I tried getting it with `e.target.value` via `onMouseOver` event, but it returned undefined.

I think I get the reason behind it, because the `event.target` returns an html node of type `<span>`.

With a normal `div` element `e.target.value` has worked in the past for me. But doing the same thing with a predefined component like antd's `Text` seems a bit trickier.

Just to elaborate, the Popover has two buttons and based on which button user clicks, I need to render some other components, something like an overlay component.

But in order to do that I would also need to get hold of the text value which originally triggered the Popover.

Below is the code(most of the things removed for preciseness).

**record.name** is what I ultimately need to capture.

```js
    <Popover
        content={
            <>
                <Space>
                    <Button onClick={showSomeOverlayPaneForName}>
                        {"View Details for record.name"}
                    </Button>
                    <Button href={"https://abc.xyz.com/" + record.role}>
                        {"View Role Details"}
                    </Button>
                </Space>
            </>
        }
        trigger={"hover"}
    >
        <Text style={{"color": blue.primary}} copyable={true} onMouseOver={handleOnMouseOverName}>{record.name}</Text>
    </Popover>
```

The **handleOnMouseOverName** function(which doesn't work anyway) :

```js
const handleOnMouseOverName = (e) => {
    //console.log("e.target.value :--- ", e.target.value);
    setCurrentActiveName(e.target.value)
}
```

And once my **currentActiveName** variable is set(via useState), I use that value inside my function **showSomeOverlayPaneForName**

```js
const showSomeOverlayPaneForName = (e) => {
    axios
        .get(
            `some-url`,
            {
                params: {name: currentActiveName}
            }
        )
        .then((response) => {
            setData(response.data);

        }).catch(reason => {
        //xyz
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass on the `record` of the enclosing `render` function to the `handleOnMouseOverName` function.

Check the following example

```js
    import React from 'react';
    import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
    import './index.css';
    import { Space, Table, Button, Popover } from 'antd';

    const App = () => {
      const data = [
        {
          key: '1',
          name: 'John Brown',
          address: 'New York No. 1 Lake Park',
          role: 'admin',
        },
        {
          key: '2',
          name: 'Jim Green',
          address: 'London No. 1 Lake Park',
          role: 'user',
        },
        {
          key: '3',
          name: 'Joe Black',
          address: 'Sidney No. 1 Lake Park',
          role: 'manager',
        },
      ];

      const columns = [
        {
          title: 'Name',
          dataIndex: 'name',
          key: 'name',
          render: (name, record) => {
            const content = (
              <>
                <Space>
                  <Button
                    onClick={() => {
                      viewDetail(record);
                    }}
                  >
                    {'View Details for ' + record.name}
                  </Button>
                  <Button href={'https://abc.xyz.com/' + record.role}>
                    {'View Role Details'}
                  </Button>
                </Space>
              </>
            );
            return (
              <>
                <Popover content={content} title="Details">
                  <div
                    onMouseOver={() => {
                      handleOnMouseOverName(record);
                    }}
                  >
                    {name}
                  </div>
                </Popover>
              </>
            );
          },
        },
        {
          title: 'Address',
          dataIndex: 'address',
          key: 'address',
        },
      ];

      const handleOnMouseOverName = (record) => {
        console.log(record);
      };

      const viewDetail = (record) => {
        console.log(record);
      };

      return <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} />;
    };

    export default App;
```

Output:

[image: GIF]

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

From antd docs: https://ant.design/components/popover/#header

Apparently you're supposed to render the `<Popover/>` with a `content={content}`-prop

For example

```js
const content = <div>Content to render under title</div>

const App = () => {
const value = "Text to hover";

 return (
  <Popover content={content} title="Title">
    <Text>{value}</Text>
  </Popover>
 )
}
```

Comment: I already have the Popover with some other contents that I didn't include in the op just for simplicity. I'll add the details in the op.

Comment: My bad. I can understand the reason for confusion. Just added few more details. In short :  Popover is activated for every row-element in a table and I want to capture the value of row-element which actually triggered the Popover.